# Command to find a string and delete it from a file

Tags: unix, replace, text-files

I have a property file `mail.properties`. The content of the file is

```
ErrorEmailTo.server1=abc_1@gmail.com,bcd_1@gmail.com,efg_1@gmail.com 
ErrorEmailFrom.server1=abc_1@gmail.com,bcd_1@gmail.com,efg_1@gmail.com
ErrorEmailCC.server1=abc_1@gmail.com,efg_1@gmail.com,bcd_1@gmail.com
```

...and numerous such entries.

I want to find `bcd_1@gmail.com` and delete it wherever it is present.  The output property file (`mail.properties`) should look like :

```
ErrorEmailTo.server1=abc_1@gmail.com,efg_1@gmail.com 
ErrorEmailFrom.server1=abc_1@gmail.com,efg_1@gmail.com
ErrorEmailCC.server1=abc_1@gmail.com,efg_1@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed 's/bcd_1@gmail.com,\?//g; s/,*$//' mail.properties
```

Use `-i` option for in-place edit.

```
sed -i 's/bcd_1@gmail.com,\?//g; s/,*$//' mail.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/bcd_1@gmail\.com//g' -e 's/,,/,/g' -e 's/,$//g' -e 's/=,/=/g' mail.properties > mail.properties_new
```